# SVG url cursor not changing cursor

Tags: jquery, svg, cursor

Here is the code:

```
 var svgUrl = "url('" + 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"' +
              ' version="1.1" width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" ' +
              ' style="fill: red;"/></svg>' + 
              "'), auto;";
```

This does not work:

```
 $("body").css('cursor', svgUrl);
```

This works as expected:

```
 $("body").css('cursor', "wait");
```

I tried to insert the SVG tag to render it as plain HTML and it does render a circle so I think the SVG markup is OK. I split the svgUrl line to make it more readable.  I have narrowed the issue and provided simple code to resolve the main problem. In the application, the cursor will change dynamically...

**EDIT after accepting answer:**

The accepted answer resolves the question asked. However, I am wondering why, if I used the string provided in the answer, this does not work?

```
    var theCursor = "url(\"" + "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'" +
                    " version='1.1' width='32' height='32'%3E%3Ccircle cx='16' cy='16' r='16'" +
                    " style='fill: blue;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\"), auto;";

    $("body").css('cursor', theCursor);
```

Comment: If you are doing this: `$("body").css('cursor', theCursor);` you will get an inline style that is enclosing your rule in quotation marks messing once again with the quotes. To understand what is happening open the inspector and look at the new inline style element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I've rewritten the cursor rule keeping your concatenation. Please note that some quotes are escaped.
2. To make it work I'm creating a new `<style>` element in the `<head>` and I'm setting the `textContent = theCursor;`

```js
var s = document.createElement("style");
document.head.appendChild(s);

let theCursor = "body{cursor: url(\"" + "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'"
+
    " version='1.1' width='32' height='32'%3E%3Ccircle cx='16' cy='16' r='16'" + 
    " style='fill: blue;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\"), auto;}";

s.textContent = theCursor;
```

```css
body{
  height:100vh;
 /* 
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='32' height='32'%3E%3Ccircle cx='16' cy='16' r='16' style='fill: red;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"), auto;}
  */
  
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="32" height="32">
  <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16"  style="fill: red;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please see the edited question. Your answer is accepted as it does answer the question asked. Thanks